# Interactive elements of a PDF being hidden when viewed in iOS/Android et al

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, android, ios

we have created an interactive PDF in InDesign CC for a client with rollovers on various charts, that display extra information when rolled over.

Now obviously the rollovers are meaningless on touch based devices, but we have found that the chart underneath is also not being displayed.

Here it is viewed in Adobe Acrobat Reader XI:
[image: how it should look]

And here is the rollover in the same:
[image: rollover]

And this is the same page in iOS etc:
[image: broken]

Now I understand that interactive elements are disabled in a lot of PDF readers, but is there a way of saying "if interactivity is disabled, display this"?

Comment: What functionality are you using to create the rollover effect? e.g. is is a mouse over event, a "button" etc. Additionally, are both images defined in the event/function or is one a base layer and the extra image defined in the rollover?

Comment: @horatio They are all set-up as buttons with an 'on click/go to destination' event/action. The rollover effect is part of the button also. I think you're right in that the initial element should not be part of the button at all. We're trying this now.

Comment: @horatio - and the designer responsible has just clocked out... thank you for your help, we will have to pick this up on monday! (and I don't have enough rep here to even up-vote you I'm afraid)

Comment: As suggested by horatio we changed the off state of the button to be in the base layer. The button was changes to have no off state, and just an over state and it now degrades gracefully on touch based devices.

Comment: Was more a question about the construction than an answer. Glad to have led you to it. It is OK to post your solution as an answer and mark your own answer as "accepted"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by horatio we changed the off state of the button to be in the base layer. The button was changed to have no off state, and just an over state and it now degrades gracefully on touch based devices.

That said, a lot of PDF readers built in to browsers, like the one in Chrome, will "helpfully" highlight buttons in a PDF, meaning that there is a tint over areas of the PDF where those invisible buttons are. We have found no way around this, and just added a caveat saying basically "this PDF works best when opened in Adobe Acrobat".